# What design pattern to use when calling Run method inside Main?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

Many times I have seen inside `Main` method of the program, independently of programming language, the following pattern but I don't know how is called and why is used like this. What can I achieve buy using something like the following inside `Main`? There are any alternatives/variations?

```
class Program     
{     
    static void Main(string[] args)     
    {     
        new Program().Run();     
    }     

    private void Run()     
    {     
        var rep = new Repository();     

        dynamic data = rep.GetPerson();     
        Console.WriteLine(data.Name);  

        dynamic data2 = rep.GetPersonWrappedInAnonymousType();     
        Console.WriteLine(data2.Person.Name);     
    }     
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Also if you see something in many parts, yes it is a pattern. This is the definition of a pattern!

Comment: This is not a pattern. The code is for demo purpose. It is written in this way so it is compile-able.

Comment: It is helpful in structuring your code and readability too. It helps you to do testable and plug able classes. http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern

Comment: Look cargo-cultish to me.  A gui programmer that thinks that Application.Run() is essential.  It certainly is for a gui app, not here.

Comment: @kennyzx I totally disagree with you. If you see something common many times yes it is a pattern. Thats exactly the definition of this word. There no any bible that defines every pattern! Open your mind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately no one was willing to answer my question so i have to accept my own answer. However i do believe there are people who can give a more experience based answer on this. So the answer is yes this is a pattern! Is called `The command pattern`.

From [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) :

> In object-oriented programming, the command pattern is a behavioral design pattern in which an object is used to represent and encapsulate all the information needed to call a method at a later time. This information includes the method name, the object that owns the method and values for the method parameters.
>
> Four terms always associated with the command pattern are command, receiver, invoker and client. A command object has a receiver object and invokes a method of the receiver in a way that is specific to that receiver's class. The receiver then does the work. A command object is separately passed to an invoker object, which invokes the command, and optionally does bookkeeping about the command execution. Any command object can be passed to the same invoker object. Both an invoker object and several command objects are held by a client object. The client contains the decision making about which commands to execute at which points. To execute a command, it passes the command object to the invoker object.
>
> Using command objects makes it easier to construct general components that need to delegate, sequence or execute method calls at a time of their choosing without the need to know the class of the method or the method parameters. Using an invoker object allows bookkeeping about command executions to be conveniently performed, as well as implementing different modes for commands, which are managed by the invoker object, without the need for the client to be aware of the existence of bookkeeping or modes.

Comment: No, I do not agree that is not a "command" pattern. It is true that the "command" pattern describes having an object that should "hold all the information needed to call (..)", and in your case action is just parameterless Run(), but the idea of "command" pattern is not solely telling you how the implementation should look like. Please for example read [this article and discussions](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CommandPattern).

Comment: The, rethink: you have just Program and Run, even no an interface for the Run method. Does it allow you to for example store some various commands, or execute them later or in different place? Does your so-called command(s) contain enough information to determine what will happend and for example try to undo, redo or batch them?

Comment: My, even look at your citation from Wiki article. Second paragraph: `Four terms always associated with the command pattern are command, receiver, invoker and client.` Does your code have clearly distinguished `command, receiver, invoker, client` parts? No.

Comment: Whoops. Sorry for all the typos everywhere, I just noticed it. The first line of the first comment should be: "No, I do not agree that is a "command" pattern.". Sorry for any confusion. 5 minutes passed and I can't correct that anymore.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl the example i provide in my original post first of all is not mine and second is clearly a variation. You just read the bible and follow. The things are not black or white always. Look at the second example in wikipedia article!

Comment: Yet again, no, it is not a variation. Examples from the Wiki are quite clear about that. Please review the examples and please, read the explantions and highlight that I have provided in response to your reasoning. The "simpler" example in that Wiki article really does have "Run()" method, but this is not indicative. The important part is that there are several distinctive command classes/structures, that they pack/contain/carry some parameters for the action to be done, and that there is some "receiver" object that the commands are sent to for execution. Code you presented does not have it.

Comment: The fact that there is some "work to do" encapsulated with a dedicated class does not yet mean that's a command. The reason why the "command" has its name is that it is a, literally, "command" that will be constructed and passed to something-completely-else that will execute that command. It is irrelevant wether that something-else will call back to the command object or not. What's important is the "passing" part. Would you say that `new Context().People.Count()` is a command pattern? I doubt. Yet they are almost the same.

Comment: `new Context().Exec( ctx=>ctx.People.Count() )` could be a command pattern, since even if bloated and conceptually identical - it has the required points: there is "job description", there is "passing the job" and there is the receiver.

Comment: If you take a cow and minimize and simplify it - remove the horns, hooves, legs, tail, gut the body and put inside a gadget that says "moo" - it may still resemble a cow, but it is not a cow.

Comment: Your opinion does not convince me. I investigated it on pluralsight (`Design Patterns Library`) and is exactly how i believe it is! It's called `The command pattern`

Answer (score 1):

Making the `Program` class able to be instantiated (instead of making everything static) allows to have multiple "programs" running at the same time or one after the other. This is useful for testing purposes.

Probably, there are instance fields in this class. By using a fresh instance each time each test run is isolated from the other ones.

Now, if there is no instance state this is a useless thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

If this is a pattern at all, it might be something around responsibility separation. You could pack it into one method:

```
class Program     
{     
    static void Main(string[] args)     
    {     
        var rep = new Repository();     

        dynamic data = rep.GetPerson();     
        Console.WriteLine(data.Name);  

        dynamic data2 = rep.GetPersonWrappedInAnonymousType();     
        Console.WriteLine(data2.Person.Name);     
    }     
}
```

but the person that wrote it wanted to separate the "start" of the program (standard "main" entry point) with the actual task(s) that is to be performed (get person, getpersonwrapped..).

Instantiating and object of "Program" class is IMHO for purists. It's highly uncommon to actually have multiple instances of these objects in a single project. However, Java/C# fans that often claim that in OOP "everything is an object" and despise everything what's `static` and not bound to objects. The `static void main` is a great pain for them, and so they quickly de-static-ize the Program class in this way. I didn't want to judgde that, but I agree with HansPassant's comment - looks cargo-cultish. But for me, that's no difference and just a tiny cosmetical change, and as I said, especially for the Program class it is mostly irrelevant. But I wouldn't call that a "design pattern". A "code style", or "implementation pattern", but not "design". There's really no architecture and no algorithm in creating and running a "run" method.

If you add more bits to that, some common interface that defines the Run(), some choosing-the-right-program implementation at runtime, then maybe you could get into, I dont know, maybe design pattern called "policy" or "strategy".. but that's mostly exaggerated